# Clarification needed in Sql query for Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table called sites where there are multiple records for the same name. For Eg.:

```
     Owner Name                      Owner Address    
            A                           XYZ
            A                           ABC
            B                           QWE
            B                           JKL
            C                           ZXC            
            B                           BNM
```

My sql query should return

```
A1           XYZ
A2           ABC
B1           QWE
B2           JKL 
B3           BNM
C            ZXC
```

Could someone give me pointers to write such a query.I am having problem grouping records with same owner name and then applying sequence each time for a different owner name.

Comment: which database engine you are using sql server or mysql ?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph, there are a few more options than that :-)./

Comment: Why doesn't `C` get a number as well?

Comment: I am using oracle.Single records like C shouldn't have any sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what database system you're using (**SQL** = Structured Query Language - that's a query language - not a database system....) - but if you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer or any other RDBMS that supports CTE's (common table expressions) and the `ROW_NUMBER` function, you could use:

```
;WITH data AS 
(
    SELECT OwnerName, OwnerAddress,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerName ORDER BY OwnerAddress)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT
    OwnerName + CAST(RN AS CHAR(1)), OwnerAddress
FROM Data
```

That returns as output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OwnerName + Convert(NVARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerName ORDER BY OwnerName)),
       OwnerAddress
FROM   dbo.OwnerTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: If you are using SQL server 2005 or above

```
   ;with cte as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Owner_Name 
    order by Owner_Address desc) as row_num  from sites),
cte1 as(select Owner_Name
    from cte 
    group by Owner_Name
    having COUNT(*)>1)
    select case when C.Owner_Name in (select Owner_Name from cte1) 
       then Owner_Name+CAST(row_num as varchar(10)) 
       else Owner_Name end as Owner_Name,Owner_Address 
       from cte C
       order by Owner_Name
```

**Result Set**

[image]